# AuthenticationContinuationHelper class not found in MSAL on Xamarin.Forms Droid

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to create a fresh Xamarin Forms application that authenticates using an AAD B2C tenant. I've based the app code on the official sample here on GitHub (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native) and when I clone this it builds, runs and authenticates fine with my tenant.

When I try to recreate this sample from scratch as a new Xamarin Forms Application using PCL for code sharing I can't get it to work. Firstly I had to change the PCL profile from it's default 259 to Profile7 to be able to install MSAL version 1.1.0-preview. And when I copy & paste the code from the github sample code the Droid version of the Forms app I get two issues in MainActivity.cs

- "UIParent' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments"
- "The name 'AuthenticationContinuationHelper' does not exist in the current context"

I've tried to create new projects from scratch on both Mac's and PC's. I also tried to copy each project's packages.config but no luck getting this to work from a fresh, new project. The Xamarin Forms IOS project can use a constructor with 1 argument and finds the required AuthenticationContinuationHelper class.

Anyone have an idea what I do wrong?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a moment to review the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour , 
How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , and more specifically, 
*How to Ask Good Questions* https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
- you'll get better feedback and helpful answers if you put some thought in to your problem before coming to SO for help, and by including a specific problem with code *that you've tried* showing effort to solve the problem yourself. You can edit your post once you have an idea of the specific issue.

Answer (score 4):

There is a bug somewhere in the MSAL NuGet installer.

When you create a new Xamarin Forms Application solution in either Visual Studio 2017 (win) or Visual Studio for Mac the Droid project gets the wrong dll referenced.

The nuget installer installs the dll from "/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client.1.1.0-preview/lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.Identity.Client.dll" into the Android project. The PCL and iOS projects gets correct dll's

If you manually remove the referenced netstandard1.3 dll and add dll from monoandroid70 directory the code works again.

I have filed an issue for this at the MSAL library project: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/441

Answer (score 2):

Had the same "AuthenticationContinuationHelper" issue. I had to set the "Target Framework" to "Android 9.0 (Pie)".
In Visual Studio, it's under Android Project properties -> Application -> Compile using Android version.